# Returning promise value from function

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I am trying to make this recursive function return a promise value, I don't know how to go about doing it, I have tried writing it in different ways but they all ended up with `search` being `undefined`

```
public search(message: Message) {
    let search: string;
    const filter = (msg: Message) => msg.author.id === message.author.id;
    message.channel.send('Enter search term').then(msg => {
      message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 })
        .then(collected => {
            if (collected.first()!.content === 'Test') this.search(message);
            msg.delete()
            collected.first()!.delete()
            search = collected.first()!.content
          })
        })
    })
    return search; // Variable 'search' is used before being assigned.ts(2454)
  }
```

Comment: If you want to return a promise, why do you try to `return search`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using an async function? That alone would make your code easier to debug and understand.

```
public async search(message: Message): Promise<any> {
    const filter = (msg: Message) => msg.author.id === message.author.id;
    const msg = await message.channel.send('Enter search term');
    const collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 });
    if (collected.first()!.content === 'Test') return this.search(message);
    msg.delete();
    collected.first()!.delete();
    const search = collected.first()!.content;
    return search;
}
```

Here, `search` is defined as a const and immediately returned, and that's fine to the compiler.
I didn't use a variable to save the return value of the nested `this.search` call, but you may have to if you decide to execute more code after calculating the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

`search` will always be undefined because the function returns before any asynchronous action returns. You need to return the first Promise and then perform any further asynchronous actions within the `.then` callbacks:

```js
public search(message: Message) {
  const filter = (msg: Message) => msg.author.id === message.author.id;
    // immediately return the first promise
  return message.channel.send('Enter search term').then(msg => {
    // then when we get a message out of the first promise return the second one
    return message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 }).then(collected => {
      // then return the desired value at the end
      if (collected.first()!.content === 'Test') this.search(message);
      msg.delete();
      collected.first()!.delete();
      return collected.first()!.content;
    });
  });
}
```

Ideally, we want to avoid nesting promises to get rid of the deep callback hell that they were invented to destroy:

```js
public search(message: Message) {
  const filter = (msg: Message) => msg.author.id === message.author.id;
  return message.channel.send('Enter search term')
    .then(msg => Promise.all([
      msg,
      message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 })
    ]))
    .then(([msg, collected]) => {
      if (collected.first()!.content === 'Test') this.search(message);
      msg.delete();
      collected.first()!.delete();
      return collected.first()!.content;
    });
}
```

By using `Promise.all` we can avoid having to nest promises and still have access to previously resolved values.

Comment: The issue I'm facing now is when I meet the condition it returns anyway and causes the rest of the code to run making the recursive function useless