# Trying to return a promise's value from function

Tags: node.js, arrays, promise, geoip, maxmind

Good morning,
please I'm trying to return array value from function... but it always result in **undefined** when I try to use any value of the array like **GetASN('128.101.101.101').autonomousSystemNumber** and **promise {  }** when I try to return the whole array...

please note that I tried these methods too but it didn't work...:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719247/8704593
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51882019/8704593

---

```
async function GetASN(ipaddress) {
        if(validateIPAddress(ipaddress) == false) return null;

        let GeoResponse = {};
        GeoIPReader.open(path.join(__dirname, 'databases/GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb')).then(await function (reader) {
            GeoResponse = reader.asn(ipaddress);
            console.log(GeoResponse.autonomousSystemNumber);
            console.log(GeoResponse.autonomousSystemOrganization);
        });
        return GeoResponse;
}
```

Comment: You need to return the Promise - right now you're returning the object before it's been populated. `return GeoIPReader.open` then modify the object and return it *inside the `.then`*. (also, `await function` doesn't make sense, just use `function`)

Comment: sorry... i didn't understand you, please can you explain

Comment: thanks dude!!! it worked... (in fact, it token much time to understand what you meant)